How could I add bodies of water to raster data?
I have a raster layer, which has latitudes and longitudes at a given resolution that determines the total number of grid cells. My goal is to find the distance from each cell to a body of water. How can I go about incorporating bodies of water into the data? Or, should I simply take the raster and add it to something else that already has that data? Is there a source for this? Thanks!
By the way, I did try Googling this, but all of the questions I saw are much more complicated. I've shared code below.
EDIT:
dat<-load('path/data.Rdata')
dat
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 229, 216, 49464, 52  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.508, 0.24  (x, y)
extent     : -149.975, -40.247, 19.92736, 74.88736  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : mallar3_p//.1.1.1.1.1, mallar3_p//.2.1.1.1.1, 
mallar3_p//.1.2.1.1.1, mallar3_p//.2.2.1.1.1, mallar3_p//.1.1.2.1.1, 
mallar3_p//.2.1.2.1.1, mallar3_p//.1.2.2.1.1, mallar3_p//.2.2.2.1.1, 
mallar3_p//.1.1.1.2.1, mallar3_p//.2.1.1.2.1, mallar3_p//.1.2.1.2.1, 
mallar3_p//.2.2.1.2.1, mallar3_p//.1.1.2.2.1, mallar3_p//.2.1.2.2.1, 
mallar3_p//.1.2.2.2.1, ... 
min values :                     0,                     0,                     
0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     
0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     
0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     
0, ... 
max values :          0.0007933783,          0.0010485946,          
0.0006397116,          0.0006564575,          0.0006783239,          
0.0007855534,          0.0008396646,          0.0007511564,          
0.0005148308,          0.0006255456,          0.0006670767,          
0.0006578597,          0.0006157646,          0.0003092461,          
0.0005634251, ... 


I recommend you provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking this type of question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. To provide an example of your raster, you can create a representative object using code,  or as a last resort, add a download link. Ensure your download link does not require authentication.

Thx. I'm still new to this and don't know how to create an example raster. My dataset was given to me. I'll see if I can figure out how to create a fake raster from scratch and then use that in my post.

How detailed do you need the water bodies to be? Do you need fresh water only, sea/ocean only, lakes only, rivers only, or all of the above?

My map is of an animal species in the US and Canada. So I desire all bodies of water in that area. Good question. I believe just all freshwater suffices.

One more question. What results do you want? Mean value within x distance? So for example, divide distance to water body into 10 bins and get the mean value for each distance bin? Or something else?

Please- ask away! I apologize for not being as descriptive as I should. So, I want the distance between each grid cell and the closest body of water. I said freshwater before, but at this early stage any body would work. The only problem I foresee is most cells have water in them, making the distance 0 for them. In such a case, I'll just increase resolution. Later on, I can be more picky about the water type I want to look at which should also mitigate this issue.

Given your RasterBrick has 52 layers, and your intended analysis is not clear, here is a generalisable approach that will create a raster object containing distance in metres to the nearest water body. Methodologically speaking, it makes sense in your case to have a separate raster with distance values which you can then use as the basis of your analysis.
This reprex uses lakes data from the rnaturalearth package. rnaturalearth also has river data etc. You can make a composite sf with any number of source data if you need.
As the CRS of your RasterBrick is WGS84/EPSG:4326, you need to ensure your other data have the same CRS. In this case, WGS84/EPSG:4326 is the default CRS for rnaturalearth data.
The cells in the distance to water body RasterLayer created by the following code align with your original RasterBrick object. This may or may not be the best approach for your analysis, but it does keep things simple. Also, as the closest water body to a given cell may be outside the extent of your RasterBrick, the extend() function is used to pad the water body RasterLayer by n number of cells (10 in this case). You can increase the extend() values if necessary.
One further point is that raster() and sp() have been deprecated, so to future-proof your work, I encourage you to migrate to the terra package.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# Download North America lakes and simplify
lakes_na <- ne_download(scale = 10,
                        type = "lakes_north_america",
                        category = "physical") |> 
  dplyr::select() |>
  st_combine() |>
  st_as_sf()

# Define the metadata variables from your example
nrow <- 229
ncol <- 216
nlayers <- 52
xmin <- -149.975
xmax <- -40.247
ymin <- 19.92736
ymax <- 74.88736

# Create a template for a water bodies RasterLayer based on your metadata
r <- raster(nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, 
            xmn = xmin, xmx = xmax, ymn = ymin, ymx = ymax, 
            crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

# Extend template RasterLayer to account for water bodies near extent of your data
r <- extend(r, c(10, 10))

# Rasterize water bodies (lakes_na)
rw <- raster::rasterize(lakes_na, r, field = 1, background = NA)

# Calculate distance to the nearest water body
d2w <- distance(rw)

# Convert to df (for illustrative purposes)
d2w_df <- as.data.frame(d2w, xy = TRUE)

# Create polygon sf of extent of your RasterBrick (for illustrative purposes)
sf_poly <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = xmin,
                               ymin = ymin,
                               xmax = xmax,
                               ymax = ymax))) |>
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326)

ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data = d2w_df,
            aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_sf(data = sf_poly,
          aes(colour = "RasterBrick extent"),
          fill = NA,
          linewidth = 1) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Distance to water (m)") +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "")

Note that d2w extends beyond the extent of your RasterBrick:


Thank you so much for this. To clarify, each layer is a different time point. I forgot about that. One question: Why does the resulting dataframe d2w_df have more cells than the data's 49,464? I should have a distance corresponding to each original cell, correct?

Actually, I figured out that the resulting raster "d2w_df" has more cells due to the fact that we extend the area to account for closest bodies of water outside of our scope. Good thinking. Is there a way to subset this raster such that we only look at those within the original boundaries?

@LifeisGood94 - if you need your water bodies RasterLayer to match the extent of your RasterBrick, just skip r <- extend(r, c(10, 10)).

Done. Thank you so much for your help.

@LifeisGood94 - if you click the hyperlink in my answer, it'll direct you to the rnaturalearth site. It contains a list of all available datasets, including rivers. For you, you can use rivers_na <- ne_download(scale = 10, type = "rivers_north_america", category = "physical"). If you need a more detailed dataset, do an internet search for "North America rivers shp download" and you'll get a number of options. To load any downloaded spatial vector data you find, first unzip it if necessary then use sf::st_read().

Wonderful. Thank you very much.
